# How to fetch new window creation / termination with WQL query?

Tags: windows, mfc, wql

Hello Hello Thanks a lot for reading this question.

I am currently building a project which requires to detect new window creation and termination

Current WQL query I am using is following.

```
hres = pSvc->ExecNotificationQueryAsync(
    _bstr_t("WQL"), 
    _bstr_t("SELECT * " 
        "FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1"
        "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"), 
    WBEM_FLAG_SEND_STATUS, 
    NULL, 
    pStubSink);
```

However, this just fetches new process creation and termination. Therefore not so useful for my project.

If there is any WQL query that you know which fetches new window creation and termination, please let me know.

I will be grateful.

Again, Thank you so much for reading this question.

Comment: Any reason you are pulling in a dependency on WMI instead of directly using [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/winevents-infrastructure)?

Comment: @IInspectable How can I implement WinEvents? Could you give me any example code or link of web site, please?

Comment: What's wrong with the link you already have?

Comment: @IInspectable Nothing. I was just wondering if there is any example code.

Comment: Yes, [there is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook). It's literally **two** clicks away from the link I posted.

Comment: @IInspectable My bad. Sorry